# Raphael Line Chart Axis labels overlapping with Axis lines

Tags: javascript, raphael, linechart, axis-labels

[image: Labels overlapping axis]

When plotting a custom label for line chart axis, on rotation of label the label's text overlaps with axis. How can one solve this issue? I tried searching documentation and found Element.transform() is to be used for rotation instead of rotate() since its depreciated, but I'm not able to make it work.
Can some one help?

```
   var lines1 = r.linechart(100, 50, 950, 470, x,
                             y, {
                                smooth : false,
                                symbol : 'circle',
                                axis : "0 0 1 1",
                                axisxstep: 20,
                                axisystep:20
                            }).hoverColumn(function () {
                                this.tags = r.set();
                                     for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i &lt; ii; i++) {
                                            this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i], 160, 5).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));
                                        }
                                    }, function () {
                                        this.tags &amp;&amp; this.tags.remove();
                                    }); 

                         var axisItems = lines1.axis[0].text.items
                        for( var i = 0, l = axisItems.length; i &lt; l; i++ ) {
                           var date = new Date(parseInt(axisItems[i].attr("text")));
                           axisItems[i].rotate(270,this.x ,this.y);
                           axisItems[i].attr("text", dateFormat(date, "dmmm,htt")); 
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this... but I end up writing my own label function

```
if (props.label !== undefined) {
    // don't use the default Raphael label() function, is broken
    chart.customLabel = customLabelFn;
    chart.customLabel(props.label);
}
```

Where customLabelFn is how i draw my labels, this is an example I have for my vertical bar chart:

```
customLabelFn = function (labels) {
    var x, y;
    labels = labels || [];

    for (var i = 0; i < props.bars.length; i++) {
        x = props.bars[i].x;
        y = props.bars[i].y + props.bars[i].h + props.xaxisLabelOffset;
        props.r.text(x, y, labels[i]);
    }
    return this;
};
```

PS: I pushed the bars into my props variable after i called Raphael to generate the chart.

```
// immediately calls the function so that we can have all the rendered bars
chart.getBars = function() {
    props.bars = (props.stacked ?
        this.bars[0] : // pick the one and only bar
        this.bars);
};
chart.getBars();
```

It works for me, and i can access the bars everywhere else, so I could use them to draw the numbers on top of bars, label, etc.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Within you `for` loop use:
`axisItems[i].translate(0,30);`

I would also recommend that you rotate 90 and not 270 so the text will extend downwards and not upwards...